# Как отправить файл методом PUT в Guzzle 6?

Tags: php, curl, fileupload, put, guzzle

Как отправить PUT запрос с файлом в Guzzle.
На curl все должно выполняться таким запросом:

```
$ curl -i -XPUT {storage_url}/new_container/new_object \    -H "X-Auth-Token: $ \    -H "X-Delete-After: 100" \    -T "./example.gz"
```

Как выполнить этот запрос в Guzzle?

Пробовал

```
$fp = fopen($localFilePath,'r');
$client->request('PUT', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'X-Auth-Token'=>$token,
        'X-Delete-After'=>100,
    ],
    'curl' => [
        CURLOPT_INFILE => $fp,
        CURLOPT_FILESIZE => filesize($localFilePath),
    ]
]);
fclose($fp);
```

Файл создается, но его размер 0 байт, т.е. запрос сервер принял и обработал, но содержимое файла не отправлено.

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает так:

- сначала инициализирую Guzzle таким способом

  ```
  use GuzzleHttp\Client;
   class Guzzle extends Client {
    public function init()
    {
      return new Client([
          'base_uri'=>'https://some_uri/api/',
          'headers'=>[
              'Authorization'=>'Token 000000-0000-0000-000000',
              'X-Vendor-ID'=>'API'
          ]
      ]);
    }
  }

  $this->guzzle = Guzzle::init();
  ```

  - потом делаю запрос в Guzzle с отправкой файла

    ```
    $response = $this->guzzle->request('PUT', 'files', ['multipart'=>[[ /*files прибавляется к base_uri т.е. адрес запроса = https://some_uri/api/files*/
      'name'=>$file_name,
      'contents'=>fopen($file,'r')    
    ]]]);
    ```

Comment: Этот метод неправильно передает content_type. При передаче .exe правильный content_type = application/x-msdownload, а на сервере показывает content_type = multipart/form-data;boundary=b4008cff4ca4bc8e9de8cb453bb29cf4df432b95 и файл получается другого размера

Comment: @atom-22 В вопросе вы вообще не указали MIME тип файла, поэтому я написал как это работает у меня + дал вам код решения. Если хотите хороший и полноценный ответ, задавайте четко сформулированный  вопрос а не возмущайтесь потом что что-то работает не так как надо.

Comment: @atom-22
удалось резрешить проблему с content_type?

Answer (score 1):

В параметр body передаем дескриптор файла

```
$fp = fopen($localFilePath,'r');
$client->request('PUT', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'X-Auth-Token'=>$token,
        'X-Delete-After'=>100,
    ],
    'body' => $fp,
]);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$multipart = [
    [
        'name'     => 'test',
        'contents' => 'test'
    ], [
        'name'     => 'files',
        'contents' => fopen(public_path($this->user->imagePath()), 'r'),
        'filename' => 'filename' . '.' . File::extension(public_path($this->user->imagePath())),
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']
        ],
    ];

$guzzleClient->request(
    'PUT',
    self::BASE_URL . '/add',
    array_merge([RequestOptions::MULTIPART => $multipart], ['headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ]])
);
```